# Splitting a Time Series Data

Tags: r

I'm trying to split an earthquake data "A" into a test and a training set.
As I used the code for time series slicing it gave this error.

`Error seq.default(1, min(ncol(x) - 1, len), by = 1) : wrong sign in 'by' argumentused` .

Thus this the data,

> structure(list(Month. = c(9L, 9L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
>   2L, 2L, 1L, 10L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 1L), Day. = c(19L, 22L, 
>   24L, 20L, 20L, 7L, 29L, 18L, 16L, 23L, 17L, 26L, 22L, 9L, 17L, 
>   12L, 16L, 11L, 27L, 25L), Mag. = c(7.1, 4.6, 4.5, 5.3, 4.9, 4.1, 
>   4.5, 4, 5.8, 4.1, 4, 4.1, 4.3, 4, 4.1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), Lat = c(18.55, 
>   18.02, 18.06, 18.07, 18.16, 18.18, 18.16, 18.06, 18.16, 18.17, 
>   17.91, 18.09, 17.84, 17.82, 18.62, 17.84, 17.93, 17.72, 18.11, 
>   18.08), Lon = c(-98.5, -98.4, -97.2, -98.52, -99.95, -99.72, 
>   -99.15, -100.02, -99.2, -99.37, -98.24, -99.58, -97.7, -99.93, 
>   -99.93, -97.74, -97.75, -99.85, -99.86, -99.98), Depth.km = c(51, 
>   50.9, 69.7, 51.8, 62.7, 45.3, 59.6, 52.7, 52, 38, 49.4, 51.7, 
>   64.8, 65, 75.7, 65.6, 63.7, 37.7, 52.1, 51.8), Day.since.Mw8.1.earthquake = c(11.55922454, 
>   -350.4447106, -410.5616088, -902.2633565, -1207.132025, -1339.944618, 
>   -1531.312454, -1542.510671, -1544.97941, -1657.711794, -1663.206956, 
>   -1685.732604, -1781.218218, -1824.403634, -1878.53603, -1914.132917, 
>   -1940.750532, -1945.763854, -1959.212801, -2052.762095)), row.names = c(NA, 
>   20L), class = "data.frame")
>   **

I  used this code for the time series slicing

I don't know what to do to clear this error. Can someone please help me out?

```
library(caret)
library(ggplot2)
library(pls)


myTimeControl <- trainControl(method = "timeslice",
                              initialWindow = 36,
                              horizon = 12,
                              fixedWindow = TRUE)

plsFitTime <- train(Day.since.Mw8.1.earthquake ~ Mag.,
                    data = A,
                    method = "pls",
                    preProc = c("center", "scale"),
                    trControl = myTimeControl)
```

Comment: When I played around with seq.default, I got that error when I tried `seq.default(1, 0, 1)`. Is it possible that ncol(x) - 1 or len ar equal to 0? I don't use this package, but maybe you're somehow taking a subset with 0 columns or observations?

Comment: If you could provide a short version of `A` to try with your code, that would let us help diagnose the problem that you are encountering.

Comment: I have no idea@JosephClarkMcIntyre.  I have included the Earthquake data in the question @Simon

Comment: I think you uploaded an image of the data and not the actual data. If you run dput(A), you can paste the result into your question (as long as it's not too long). Or else maybe you can upload the .csv the data are stored in?

Comment: @JosephClarkMcIntyre I"m trying to upload the csv file but I cant see the button here to do so. Also the dput(A) gives the output in an unstructured way

Comment: I think you might need to upload it to a Google Drive and then link to it. I don't use this package and might not be able to help much, but that will be useful if someone else who knows more than I do wants to try.

Comment: I'm giving it a try thanks

Comment: I have given the link for the data now

Comment: Use `dput(head(df,20))` to add data to your question if the `df` is too large. Links to data will likely expire in the future and/or may not be accessible by some users. Please edit your question with these suggestions in mind. Cheers!

Comment: I don't know if this will be helpful, but the issue seems to be with method = 'pls'. I used other methods from the vignette in the caret package, and although some of the returned warnings, all of them produced results. Maybe you can use a different method?

Comment: Thank you@NelsonGon . I will apply a different method to see the outcome. thank you@Joesph